# Failed to load template after Umbraco update

Tags: .net, content-management-system, umbraco

I updated Umbraco to 7.12.4 and after that, I got an error.
http://prntscr.com/mzvayv
Does anyone know how I can solve this problem?

Comment: By the way, the file exists

Comment: Try to set the debug mode in web.config so the files will not be bundled and you'll have a clearer error message 
<compilation debug="true"

Answer (score 0):

Some things to try...

Go to /app_data/TEMP/ClientDependency and delete all files

Go to /config/ClientDependency.config and increment the version number

Recycle the app pool.

Totally agree with Eyescream above - go into debug mode.

Have a peak at the /app_data/logs file to see if it reveals some error messages.

Based on your other error message about "Could not find the tree media, activeTree has not been set", this all sounds (to me) related to the media types or the Upload elements.
Try re-saving each by first going into Settings-->Media and just click and save each (File, Folder, Image)

[image]

Then I would do the same for the FileUploader and ImageCropper in Developer-->DataTypes.

[image]

And this is going to sound like a long shot, but specifically with the two data types - Be sure they are named as expected.  There was an **old** issue with the FileUpload control where sometimes a random "\t" would appear in the file name. Before you re-save those types just click up on the file name and make sure there are no extra chars after the name. I haven't seen that issue in years, but since I'm not sure what version you upgraded from?

[image]

Lastly try going into users and verifying that your user account (or whatever account you are logging in with has a Media Root node.  It can also be applied via the User's Group level

[image]

Hope this can help get you going.